# Java new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "--version").start() does not print out results

Tags: java

I want to run some commands from Java, but the following program does not print out the expected result. Any ideas?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


          Process p = new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "--version").start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not try to print anything, so an empty output is to be expected. Look at the `Process` class' javadoc and look for how to handle the process' output stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the source and destination for subprocess standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process. You can to this by calling:

[ProcessBuilder.inheritIO();](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO())

So your example should look something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
          ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("gcc", "--version");
          processBuilder.inheritIO();
          processBuilder.start()
    }

}
```

For advanced process I/O usage you should take a look at [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) JavaDocs.